# No KeyEvent.KEYCODE for $ in android

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm looking to handle a key event for the "$" symbol in a custom android keyboard.  From reading the documentation, there is no KeyEvent.KEYCODE_.  How do you get around this?  The native android keyboard has a dollar sign.  I've searched google and SO to no avail.

On the KeyBoard object they mention that the KEYCODE for the $ is KEYCODE_4, but our keyboard has no shift in this configuration.

Comment: Write a scrap activity or something, override `onKeyDown()`, and see what your keyboard generates via logging or a breakpoint. Nobody else is going to know what your specific (hardware?) keyboard generates for the `$` character. Not all punctuation has dedicated keycodes in `KeyEvent.

Comment: The problem is that our current implementation of the keyboard does not have a $ and we want to add one.

Comment: Then write a scrap activity or something, override `onKeyDown()`, and see what *other* keyboards generate via logging or a breakpoint. My guess is that you will have to send a shift meta along with `KEYCODE_4`, even though technically you don't have a shift key, but that's just a guess. I would imagine that the best course of action is to emulate what other keyboards (hard and soft) do.

Comment: Good suggestion, will do.